# Usage of torch.optim.Adam in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, adam

I am new to python and pytorch. I am struggling to understand the usage of Adam optimizer.
Please review the below line of code:

```
opt = torch.optim.Adam([y], lr=0.1)
```

This line is taking a input list. Print the value of y, I get :
`The value of [y]=  [tensor([-0.7854, -0.7854, -0.7854], requires_grad=True)]`

Now,when I print `opt`, I get:

```
The value of opt=  Adam (
Parameter Group 0
    amsgrad: False
    betas: (0.9, 0.999)
    capturable: False
    eps: 1e-08
    foreach: None
    lr: 0.1
    maximize: False
    weight_decay: 0
)
```

I am not able to understand the reason for finding `opt` and how it affects the code functionality?

Then further in the code,
they do:

```
opt.zero_grad()      # What is the use this function call?
loss, expval = cost(y)      # This is a user defined function. I am understanding it
loss.backward()         # This is a user defined function. I am understanding it
opt.step()              # What is the use this function call?
```

What `zero_grad()` and `step()` function do and how are they dependent on `opt`? A small explanation can help me up a lot.
Thank you for great help.

Comment: It's better to go through the PyTorch tutorial https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/optimization_tutorial.html#optimizer

Comment: Thank you @joe32140 for providing me the link of the Tutorial.